# JS Menu Post Get method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS ajax GET that returns menus to be used in a view. I wanted to see if there is any more way to write this method. Its a lot of code and just wanted to make sure there is no better way to do this?

```
 console.log('Processing Login ajax GetMenuLinkList')
 var url = "/login/GetMenuLinkList";
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: param = "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
     success: function (data, status) {
         console.log(data);
         $('#favoritepagesListBlock').empty();
         $('#meetingsanddisclosuresBlock').empty();
         $('#memberinstitutionBlock').empty();
         $('#orderListBlock').empty();
         var orderShowMore = false;
         var subscriptionShowMore = false;
         $.each(data, function (index, data) {
             switch (data.PageSection) {
                case 1:
                     $('#favoritepagesListBlock').append("<a class='link-text' href='"+data.Url+"'>" + data.PageName + "</a>");
                     break;
                 case 2:
                     $('#meetingsanddisclosuresBlock').append("<a class='link-text' href='" + data.Url + "'>" + data.PageName + "</a>");
                     break;
                 case 3:
                     $('#memberinstitutionBlock').append("<a class='link-text' href='" + data.Url + "'><b>" + data.PageName + "</b></a>");
                     break;
                 case 4:
                     $('#orderListBlock').append("<a class='link-text' href='" + data.Url + "'>" + data.PageName + "</a>");
                     orderShowMore = data.ShowMore;
                     break;
                 case 5:
                     $('#subscriptionListBlock').append("<a class='link-text' href='" + data.Url + "'>" + data.PageName + "</a>");
                     subscriptionShowMore = data.ShowMore;
                     break;
             }
         });


         if (orderShowMore = true) {
                 $('#orderListBlock').append("<a class='show-more' href='/home/store/order-history'>View More</a>");
         }
         if (subscriptionShowMore=true) {
                 $('#subscriptionListBlock').append("<a class='show-more' href='/home/store/subscriptions'>View More</a>");
         }


    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
     //   alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make your code work. `orderShowMore = true` is assigning `true` to `orderShowMore` - the code in the block after this is inevitably going to get executed.  Just go `if(orderShowMore)`.

Second, don't use two variables named `data` - while scoping may make it unambiguous to the compiler, it's confusing to anyone reading your code. Also, consistent indenting goes a long way.

You really don't need a switch statement there - you're basically repeating almost the same code four or five times. You could assign all the ids to a variable - probably a good idea, since I'm assuming you want to clear `$('#subscriptionListBlock')` so it doesn't fill up with junk.

This seems like a perfect oppurtunity to use template strings - you're inserting values into a string, this is pretty much what they're made for.

You might actually want to look up the [`$.ajax` docs](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) - You're meant to call with `(url, settings)` not `({url: url})`. Also, if you're not sending any data to the server, cut that out - right now, you're assigning an undeclared variable `param` to an empty string, which could cause errors if run in strict mode.

Use `let` and `const` over `var` - `var` allows redeclaration, which can cause problems and make debugging harder.

Final code:

```js
console.log('Processing Login ajax GetMenuLinkList')
let url = "/login/GetMenuLinkList";
const idList = ['#favoritepagesListBlock','#meetingsanddisclosuresBlock','#memberinstitutionBlock','#orderListBlock','#subscriptionListBlock']
$.ajax(url, {
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        for(id of idList) $(id).empty();
        let orderShowMore = false;
        let subscriptionShowMore = false;
        for(let item of data){
            $(idList[item.PageSection - 1]).append(`<a class='link-text' href='${item.Url}'>${
                item.PageSection == 3 ?
                `<b>${item.PageName}</b>` :
                iiitem.PageName
            }</a>`);
            if(item.PageSection == 4) orderShowMore = true;
            if(item.PageSection == 5) subscriptionShowMore = true;
        }

        if (orderShowMore) {
            $('#orderListBlock').append("<a class='show-more' href='/home/store/order-history'>View More</a>");
        }
        if (subscriptionShowMore) {
            $('#subscriptionListBlock').append("<a class='show-more' href='/home/store/subscriptions'>View More</a>");
        }
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        //console.log(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: `idList[data.PageSection - 1])` what is that doing? should it be `item` ?

Comment: Oops, I misadapted your code. Fixing.

Answer (score 2):

A short review;

- You inlined the success function, I would use a properly named function outside of that block
- This

  ```
     $('#favoritepagesListBlock').empty();
     $('#meetingsanddisclosuresBlock').empty();
     $('#memberinstitutionBlock').empty();
     $('#orderListBlock').empty();
  ```

  can be

  ```
     $('#favoritepagesListBlock,#meetingsanddisclosuresBlock,#memberinstitutionBlock,#orderListBlock').empty();
  ```
- `orderShowMore = data.ShowMore;` seems like a bug, I would write `orderShowMore = orderShowMore || data.ShowMore;` Same thing for `subscriptionShowMore`
- Your error handling is empty, you should fix that ;)
- In production code, your `success` function should not write to the console
- You can apply DRY techniques, a lot of the code looks copy pasted, especially this part;

  ```
    switch (data.PageSection) {
                case 1:
                     $('#favoritepagesListBlock').append("<a class='link-text' href='"+data.Url+"'>" + data.PageName + "</a>");
                     break;
                 case 2:
                     $('#meetingsanddisclosuresBlock').append("<a class='link-text' href='" + data.Url + "'>" + data.PageName + "</a>");
                     break;
                 case 3:
                     $('#memberinstitutionBlock').append("<a class='link-text' href='" + data.Url + "'><b>" + data.PageName + "</b></a>");
                     break;
                 case 4:
                     $('#orderListBlock').append("<a class='link-text' href='" + data.Url + "'>" + data.PageName + "</a>");
                     orderShowMore = data.ShowMore;
                     break;
                 case 5:
                     $('#subscriptionListBlock').append("<a class='link-text' href='" + data.Url + "'>" + data.PageName + "</a>");
                     subscriptionShowMore = data.ShowMore;
                     break;
             }
  ```